# Why Cannot call child class method from object of interface implemented in parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

```
public interface WebDriver {
    default void get() {
        System.out.println("Opening Url");}

    void click();
    void sendKeys();
}

public class RemoteWebDriver implements WebDriver {
    @Override
    public void click() {
        System.out.println("Clicking WebElement");
    }

    @Override
    public void sendKeys() {
        System.out.println("Entering Text");
    }
}

public class ChromeDriver extends RemoteWebDriver {
    public void clear() {
        System.out.println("Clearing Text");
    }
}

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get();
        driver.click();
        driver.sendKeys();
        driver.clear();
    }
}
```

driver.clear(); in TestClass gives error. 
"The method clear() is undefined for the type WebDriver"

2 quick fixes available:

- Create method clear() in type WebDriver
- Add cast to webdriver

I know this

```
((ChromeDriver) driver).clear();
```

fixes the problem. But could anyone explain more logically, why it is not allowing to call child class methods

Comment: Well look at the compile-time type of `driver` - it's just `WebDriver`. By the time you reach the call `driver.clear()`, the compiler *only* has that information to go on - and the `WebDriver` interface doesn't have a `clear()` method. You *happen* to have initialized the variable using a `ChromeDriver` reference, but that's not part of the information the compiler can or should use in the call `driver.clear()`.

Comment: Another option you haven't mentioned is just changing the type of the `driver` variable to `ChromeWebDriver`. If you *rely* on the value of the variable being a `ChromeWebDriver` (which it looks like you do) then that's the most appropriate fix, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Because at compile time it will check method in parent class or interface, so it will give compilation error if method not found in parent interface